# Can't find my Mac partitions when installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning

I followed a tutorial and created 2 new partitions on my Macbook Air.

I have created 160GB for my ubuntu and 10GB for my SWAP space. However, when installing ubuntu, I can't find anything on the installation type. I can't find my partitions to install Ubuntu.

[image: Image of partitions in gparted]

Here is my file system

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    1  14.6G  0 disk /cdrom
├─sda1   8:1    1     2G  0 part 
└─sda2   8:2    1   2.4M  0 part 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           384M  1.7M  383M   1% /run
/dev/sda        2.0G  2.0G     0 100% /cdrom
/cow            1.9G  683M  1.3G  36% /
tmpfs           1.9G   53M  1.9G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.9G  516K  1.9G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           384M   52K  384M   1% /run/user/999
```

Here is what my Mac looks like, with its **APFS Encrypted partitions**.

[image: mac_info]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Mac APFS partitions are encrypted, so you can't see them with Ubuntu.

You made the swap partition with APFS, not ext4, so you can't use it. I'd delete that and use a swap file instead. Ever since Fall 2017, you don't need to create a separate swap partition, as swap files since run as fast and reliably as swap partitions. Swap recommendationsare shown at http://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq